# .gitignore failed to ignore a newly created text file

Tags: git, msysgit

I can't seem to work out why my .gitignore isn't ignoring a simple text file. I have read the manual and I think I've done all required steps.

Firstly I created a new repo like this:

```
C:\> mkdir test
C:\> cd test
C:\test> git init
```

Then I created and comitted a .gitignore which ignores a file called junk.txt

```
C:\test [master]> touch .gitignore
C:\test [master +1 ~0 -0 !]> echo 'junk.txt' >> .gitignore
C:\test [master +1 ~0 -0 !]> git add .gitignore
C:\test [master +1 ~0 -0]> git commit -m 'ignoring junk.txt'
```

By now I would assume if I have a file called junk.txt git would ignore it. But how come it's still saying that as an untracked file?

```
C:\test [master]> touch junk.txt
C:\test [master +1 ~0 -0 !]> git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       junk.txt
```

I'm using msysgit

```
C:\test [master +1 ~0 -0 !]> git --version
git version 1.8.0.msysgit.0
```

Comment: you can do git clean, and it'll be removed. If it is there, and not added to git, its status should be untracked.

Comment: @matt junk.txt is a new file added after .gitignore is setup, hence nothing to do with cache as mentioned on that post. I've tried to rm --cached anyway and it gives errors, and the file is still detected as untracked file

Comment: Can you verify that .gitignore contains what you think it contains? It looks like you're in Windows while typing bash commands, which is probably the source of your trouble.

Comment: What does that '+1 ~0 -0 !' part in the prompt mean? That's not what I usually see in my repository.  Additionally, repeating those steps exactly as described does ignore the file.

Comment: You are on Windows, I am betting that because you created your .gitignore file in this funny way it is invalid (bad line endings, bad encoding, something like that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gerrytan, you are using bash syntax on a system that does not use bash syntax.

Specifically, when you do the following:

```
echo 'junk.txt' >> .gitignore
```

You have told git to ignore the file 'junk.txt' *including* the quotation marks.

If you had used bash, or any sh-compatible shell, then that command would have told git to ignore 'junk.txt' *excluding* the quotation marks, because in those shells, the quotation marks indicate the word boundaries, but they have no special meaning in cmd.exe (The standard command line in windows).

I suggest you open .gitignore in an editor and take a look at the entry.

Comment: There isn't any quotation mark on .gitignore, but the way I created .gitingore seem to cause file encoding issue -- hence it's not read by git. When I created it using notepad it works as expected. Thanks for the help